# Same executable name with c file after compilation

Tags: c, gcc

I want to compile several c files and I want to have executables whose names are same as the c file's names i.e if I have trial1.c, how can I have trial1.out?

Comment: `executables`? the `s` is intentional? individual binaries?

Comment: For what reason do you not want to use the -o option?

Comment: Also, are (are not) you aware of makefiles?

Comment: `without using -o trial1` - no way. Well, you can rename `a.out` after each compilation..

Comment: because I have several c files. I am compiling them in one command and I want to see which of them were not compilled. If I could have the executables with the same name as the c file names, I could determine which of them were not compiled. -o option becomes useless in this sense.

Comment: @SamiŞimşekli Now get rid of this "without using -o" part of the question, as you just don't know how to use it properly to achieve what you need. And it can be used properly for your needs. One of the options is down there in the answer. Another would be to use a Makefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
for i in *.c; do gcc ${i::1}.c -o ${i::1}.out; done
```

Or, if you are interested on just knowing if they compile successfully:

```
for i in *.c; do gcc $i 2>/dev/null && echo "$i : OK" || echo "$i : FAIL"; done
```